# What is mapload in google maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

What is map load? Is every refresh considered a map load for google map api v3? The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usagelimits) says that one can load map 25,000 times a day (24hrs). Does that mean a single user of the website or the whole web application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage

"A map load is counted when a map is initialized on a web page. User interaction with a map after it has loaded (eg. panning the map, zooming the map, or changing from roadmap to satellite map) does not have any impact on usage limits"

Comment: does it mean 25,000 api calls  per month?